# How to pass params as a function and call it after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, function

I create my custom delete with function and parameters like this

```
function boxAlert(params){
   $('body').append(
     '<div class="box">' +
        '<div>' +params.message+ '</div>' +
        '<button onclick="' +params.action()+ '"> YES </button>' +
     '</div>'
   );
}
```

then I use it like this

```
<button onclick="_delete()"> Delete Data </button>

<script>
   function _delete(){
      boxAlert({
         message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor?',
         action: function(){ // call this after button is clicked
            alert();
         }
      });
   }
</script>
```

It's work but, the alert is called before YES button is clicked, I want alert is called after YES button is clicked, how to solve it? thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rewrite it like this:

```js
function boxAlert(params) {
  $('body').append(
    $('<div class="box">').append(
      $('<div>').text(params.message),
      $('<button>YES</button>').click(params.action)
    )
  );
}
function _delete() {
  boxAlert({
    message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor?',
    action: function () { // call this after button is clicked
      alert();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="_delete()"> Delete Data </button>
```

Use the `.click` function to specify the handler for the button element.  Also, while we're at it, use the `.text` function to specify the text for the message (which will properly escape it.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use params.actions(). Note the parentheses, you are calling the function.

Solution:

```
<button onclick="setTimeout(' +params.action.toString()+ ',0)">
```

setTimeout is required in this solution in order to execute the function.

Hope this help!

Comment: Ok. I explained. It was late and I was lazy... my english is not the best, I hope it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="' +params.action()+ '"> YES </button>
```

Will call the action and append a string to the click handler.

```
function boxAlert(params){
   let div = $('<div class="box">' +
        '<div>' +params.message+ '</div>' +
   '</div>').append($('<button> YES </button>').click(params.action));
   $('body').append(div);
}
```